# Where is AdminArea in newst GitLab install?

Tags: gitlab

I am learning GitLab from online tutorial. We are directed to spanner,but I can not find it.

[image]

This is my install,no spanner at all.

[image]

Where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are logging in as an administrator ?

Looks like you are using an account with a different level?

The default user I think is root or maybe admin ? , are you accessing with that account?

root / admin@example.com as the username ?

Link below showing how to reset PW

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_root_password.html